# Computation on large array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sympy

i have a question concerning computation of large array in python( >=3.6.8 ) on Ubuntu SO.
I have a large array A, about 20 000 000 (or more) of points (each point is a 3d coordinate x,y,z).
I would like to know which of these points are close to a given plane. I use sympy python library for representing point, plane and to compute distance.
I have another array T of planes (as sympy object), tipically an array of 7 or 10 elements.
For example, for each point p of my A array, and for each t plane, i do something like:

```
        for p in A:
            for t in T:
                if  t.distance(p) <= Delta:
                    do something
```

Obviously, if i loop this check for all points and for all plane, i achieve the result after several hours. I done this loop also using processes splitting my array of points in chunks, but also in this way, computation requires a lot of time (hours).
I read numpy has where method, but i don't know how to set condition like:

```
        for t in T:
            B = A[np.where(t.distance(Point3D(A)) <= 0.1)]
```

where:
t is a sympy plane;
Point3D is sympy class for casting generic x,y,z point into sympy point;
B is array of A indexes which satisfy condition.

where condition as above reported causes exception :"Nonzero coordinates cannot be removed".
Is there some fast approach to compute the loop into 10 or 15 minutes (max)?
Thank you in advance.
Bye.

Comment: Is your array `A` two dimensional? Since it contains 20M x-y-z points.

Comment: A is three dimensional array. Each point has 3 float value: x,y,z

Answer (score 2):

Using `map`  seems to be very fast.

Here a code test example with One Million points in 4 seconds .

in this case `map` needs a function and two iterables ,
so we need iterable points (one million) and iterable planes (one million , all the same in this case).

```
import math
import numpy as np
import time

# Function to find point plane distance
def ppdist(p, plane ):
    x1,y1,z1 = p
    a,b,c,d = plane
    d = abs((a * x1 + b * y1 + c * z1 + d))
    e = (math.sqrt(a * a + b * b + c * c))
    return d/e


# num points
numpts = 1000000
#creating random 3d points
pts = np.random.randint(0,1234,size=(numpts,3))

#plane 
a = 20
b = -20
c = 50
d = 80

plane=[a,b,c,d]
#creating a list of identical planes    
planes = [ plane for n in range( numpts ) ]
# Function call

start_time = time.time()
res_map = list(map( ppdist , pts , planes))
end_time = time.time()
elapsed = end_time-start_time
print(len(res_map), " distances in ", elapsed, "seconds")
```

output for One Million Point Plane distance computations :

```
1000000  distances in  4.155193328857422 seconds
```

I think  20M distance computations needs 4.15*20 ->  83 seconds ~
Try it and let me know.

Here an extended example to abtain a new list with the points that are at a distance less than a value , ** processing 1M points in less than 5 seconds **

```
import math
import numpy as np
import time

# Function to find point plane distance
def ppdist(p, plane ):
    x1,y1,z1 = p
    a,b,c,d = plane
    d = abs((a * x1 + b * y1 + c * z1 + d))
    e = (math.sqrt(a * a + b * b + c * c))
    return d/e

# Function returns point if distance is less than value
def pdistmin(point , dist , val):
    return point if dist < val else None

# num points
numpts = 1000000
#creating random 3d points
pts = np.random.randint(0,1234,size=(numpts,3))


#plane 
a = 20
b = -20
c = 50
d = 80

plane=[a,b,c,d]
#creating a list of identical planes    
planes = [ plane for n in range( numpts ) ]
# Function call

start_time = time.time()
res_dist = list(map( ppdist , pts , planes))
end_time = time.time()
elapsed = end_time-start_time
print(len(res_dist), " distances in ", elapsed, "seconds")


start_time = time.time()
less = [ 10 for n in range( numpts ) ]
xxx = list(map( pdistmin, pts, res_dist , less ))
end_time = time.time()
elapsed = end_time-start_time
print(len(xxx), " points or None computation in ", elapsed, "seconds")


start_time = time.time()
needed_points = [ p for p in xxx if p is not None ]
end_time = time.time()
elapsed = end_time-start_time
print(len(needed_points), " points in ", elapsed, "seconds")
```

output:

```
1000000  distances in  4.1579577922821045 seconds
1000000  points or None computation in  0.42284178733825684 seconds
   9372  points found in  0.014847517013549805 seconds
```

So less than 5 seconds for 1M points .  **Probably  100 seconds for 20M Points**

Comment: Hi Mario, thank you for suggestion. Your solution works great. I've noticed that sympy conversion (point to Point3D, to solve some algebra issues) requires a lot time. Infact when i use your code with Point3D class, i get result after a hour ... it is very strange for me. Anyway, your solution give me a fast way to compute distances. Thank you. Bye.

Comment: Hi Mario, after some tests i get the following results:  each point has 3 float coordinates (x,y,z), i have about 400 000 points. I used your example for computing distances (i use ppdist as method of my class).  Total time is  2106 seconds (35 minutes) on a virtual machine with UBUNTU 18.04 (8GB RAM and 4 CPU assigned to VM). Maybe something wrong in my code.

Comment: Try my code esactly as It Is with your virtual machine. If execution time Is too long probably the problem Is the virtual machine. Else where the slow process Is your class. Let us know.

Comment: I don't know why ... if i use list(map(    with ppdist as function outside my class, performnces are ok (i get results in few seconds), but if i call  ppdist as my class method processing last hours.

Comment: I think because ppdist as class method create a new instance of the method , so create 400K instances results in a huge process.

Comment: if i don't see the class and how you build the list to pass to the external function i can't evaluate how to optimize it. I think your initial question was met. You can 'ask a new question' in which we will talk about `map` and class objects and how to optimize. Let me know the link to the new question here so I can help you

Comment: Thank you Mario.Using your suggestions and your example i improved my computation ... Moreover, i combined map with multiprocess and now i process all points in very few seconds. Great!

Comment: Awesome @MrMartini.  Let us see the trick . it was a pleasure.

Comment: Nothing of special. My goal was to compute distance from each point of a cloud point to N planes. So, i simply created N processes each of one compute the distance between each PC points and specific plane. In this way, my VM processes PC (point cloud) with 4 M of points on 7 planes in 47 sec, and a PC with 20 M points in about 200 secs. I used multiprocessing.Process  to call your ppdist and a multiprocessing.Manager() Queue for storing results from each process.Thank you again Mario.

Answer (score 2):

SymPy is a symbolic library. The idea is that you would use it to symbolically derive a formula that you then compute using more efficient numerical libraries e.g.:

```
In [20]: x, y, z = symbols('x, y, z')

In [21]: arbitrary_point = Point3D(x, y, z)

In [22]: delta = 2

In [23]: plane = Plane(Point3D(1, 1, 1), normal_vector=(1,4,7))

In [24]: condition = plane.distance(arbitrary_point) < delta

In [25]: condition
Out[25]: 
│√66⋅(x - 1)   2⋅√66⋅(y - 1)   7⋅√66⋅(z - 1)│    
│─────────── + ───────────── + ─────────────│ < 2
│     66             33              66     │    

In [26]: f = lambdify((x, y, z), condition)

In [27]: f(2, 3, 4)
Out[27]: False

In [28]: f(1, 1, 2)
Out[28]: True
```

You can see the code used to make the lambdified function like this:

```
In [29]: import inspect

In [31]: print(inspect.getsource(f))
def _lambdifygenerated(x, y, z):
    return (less(abs((1/66)*sqrt(66)*(x - 1) + (2/33)*sqrt(66)*(y - 1) + (7/66)*sqrt(66)*(z - 1)), 2))
```

You can now use this function with numpy arrays for the `x`, `y` and `z` values:

```py
In [33]: xvals = np.arange(0, 10)

In [34]: yvals = np.arange(0, 10)

In [35]: zvals = np.arange(0, 10)

In [36]: f(xvals, yvals, zvals)
Out[36]: 
array([ True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False])
```

This will handle large arrays of inputs more efficiently e.g. 20 million points can be processed in 1 second:

```
In [38]: xvals = yvals = zvals = np.arange(0, 20*10**6)

In [39]: %time ok = f(xvals, yvals, zvals)
CPU times: user 698 ms, sys: 553 ms, total: 1.25 s
Wall time: 1.26 s
```